# Calculate average of column value in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm kind of new to Ruby on Rails. I have a profile model which has_many courses taken.

```
create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "pname"
   t.float    "current_gpa"
end
```

and

```
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer  "course_number"
   t.float    "gpa"
end
```

I want to calculate the average gpa: current_gpa = sum of gpa of courses taken / num of course taken. How can I do this?

Comment: Any error messages?  Please post those.  It is best to show some effort in your questions otherwise they are in jeopardy of not being well received.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should consider reading some documentation - obviously it's quick to get a answer on SO but sometimes the docs can lead you to something you didn't know to look for or ask for.

That said, the fastest way is to use [**`average`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average)

```
profile.courses.average(:gpa)
```

This will give you an average. Or you can do it the long way, if for some reason you need make modifications in between.

```
profile.courses.sum(:gpa) / profile.courses.count
```

Answer (score 6):

An additional note here... Average returns floating point numbers or BigDecimal which is often represented in decimal notation. This can be confusing and may not be what you are looking for. You might explore adding something like: .to_int, .to_f, .truncate, .round, etc...

```
Person.average(:age) # => 0.387e2
Person.average(:age).to_i # => 38
Person.average(:age).to_f # => 38.7
Person.average(:age).to_f.round # => 39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Calculations average](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average):

```
profile.courses.average(:gpa)
```